# Select distinct values from a list using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of Employee

```
Class Employee

{
  empName
  empID
  empLoc 
  empPL
  empShift
}
```

My list contains

```
 empName,empID,empLoc,empPL,empShift
    E1,1,L1,EPL1,S1 
    E2,2,L2,EPL2,S2
    E3,3,L3,EPL3,S3
    E4,4,L1,EPL1,S1
    E5,5,L5,EPL5,S5
        E6,6,L2,EPL2,S2
```

I need to take the employees having distinct values
   empLoc,empPL,empShift.

Is there is any way to achieve this using LINQ ?

Comment: Do you need the *whole* information for those employees, or just the empLoc, empPL and empShirt? (Your naming is pretty nasty, by the way - given that they're within an Employee class, the "emp" prefix is redundant, but "Loc" and "PL" are relatively meaningless on their own.)

Comment: @JonSkeet this is the basic requirement. I just made a class. But in original it is having lot of properties and all I  need is  to check 3 properties.I m sorry about that :( . I need the whole information . Not just empLoc, empPL and empShift .

Comment: Could you use DistinctBy from morelinq with a composite key (anonymous type)?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could implement a custom [`IEqualityComparer<Employee>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx):

```
public class Employee
{
    public string empName { get; set; }
    public string empID { get; set; }
    public string empLoc { get; set; }
    public string empPL { get; set; }
    public string empShift { get; set; }

    public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
    {
        public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return x.empLoc == y.empLoc
                && x.empPL == y.empPL
                && x.empShift == y.empShift;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
        {
            unchecked  // overflow is fine
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + (obj.empLoc ?? "").GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + (obj.empPL ?? "").GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + (obj.empShift ?? "").GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this overload of [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx):

```
var distinct = employees.Distinct(new Employee.Comparer());
```

---

The less reusable, robust and efficient approach, using an anonymous type:

```
var distinctKeys = employees.Select(e => new { e.empLoc, e.empPL, e.empShift })
                            .Distinct();
var joined = from e in employees
             join d in distinctKeys
             on new { e.empLoc, e.empPL, e.empShift } equals d
             select e;
// if you want to replace the original collection
employees = joined.ToList();
```

Comment: Tim I tried with `IEqualityComparer` and its worked fine for me . But the second solution you provide is not working fine . The distinct query is not working. It contains a list with empLoc,empPl,empShift and the join also not working as expected. Can you please have a look ? Thanks

Comment: @VeeKeyBee: The second solution is similar to  Aghilas approach. Selecting the key fields into an anonymous type, then using `Enumerable.Distinct`. But instead of selecting the anonymous type i'm joining it with the original collection of employees (note the `select e` at the end). So that should work too.

Comment: Now this is what we call a complete solution. Although I must say @Coung Le has answered with a very valuable shorter cut!

Comment: @Curious: the `GroupBy` aproach is fine. But it is more work than using a custom `IEqualityComparer`(for  CPU and memory). You can (re)use the `IEqualityComparer` for most LINQ extension methods. And if the implementation will change you only have one place to repair.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: you are correct. As my need was for a temp purpose I would go with the GroupBy approach. If the comparer is to be reused I will definitely fall back on your suggestion :)

Answer (score 43):

You can use `GroupBy` with *anonymous type*, and then get `First`:

```
list.GroupBy(e => new { 
                          empLoc = e.empLoc, 
                          empPL = e.empPL, 
                          empShift = e.empShift 
                       })

    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: This is the most convenient approach! Only if I could upvote this 10 more times :)

Comment: Which one is more efficient? The GroupBy can be a lot slower depending on the number of groups. If the groups count approaches the size of the input array and the input array size is large, then, the Distinct approach is the way to go. See my answer below

Answer (score 15):

You can try with this code

```
var result =  (from  item in List
              select new 
              {
                 EmpLoc = item.empLoc,
                 EmpPL= item.empPL,
                 EmpShift= item.empShift
              })
              .ToList()
              .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 3):

I was curious about which method would be faster:

1. Using Distinct with a custom IEqualityComparer or
2. Using the GroupBy method described by Cuong Le.

I found that depending on the size of the input data and the number of groups, the Distinct method can be a lot more performant. (as the number of groups tends towards the number of elements in the list, distinct runs faster).

Code runs in LinqPad!

```
    void Main()
    {
        List<C> cs = new List<C>();
        foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0,Int16.MaxValue*1000))
        {
            int modValue = Int16.MaxValue; //vary this value to see how the size of groups changes performance characteristics. Try 1, 5, 10, and very large numbers
            int j = i%modValue; 
            cs.Add(new C{I = i, J = j});
        }
        cs.Count ().Dump("Size of input array");

        TestGrouping(cs);
        TestDistinct(cs);
    }

    public void TestGrouping(List<C> cs)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        sw.Restart();
        var groupedCount  = cs.GroupBy (o => o.J).Select(s => s.First()).Count();
        groupedCount.Dump("num groups");
        sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("elapsed time for using grouping");
    }

    public void TestDistinct(List<C> cs)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var distinctCount = cs.Distinct(new CComparerOnJ()).Count ();
        distinctCount.Dump("num distinct");
        sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("elapsed time for using distinct");
    }

    public class C
    {
        public int I {get; set;}
        public int J {get; set;}
    }

    public class CComparerOnJ : IEqualityComparer<C>
    {
        public bool Equals(C x, C y)
        {
            return x.J.Equals(y.J);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(C obj)
        {
            return obj.J.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var newList = 
(
from x in empCollection
select new {Loc = x.empLoc, PL = x.empPL, Shift = x.empShift}
).Distinct();
```